# How do I clean up the x axis?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I have tried `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` but that doesn't fix the overlapping dates on the x axis. How do I clean the x axis to every week instead of everyday?

```
# Convert string column into date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")

plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
plt.title("Daily Tests")
plt.ylabel("Number of confirmed cases")
plt.xlabel("Date")
sns.barplot(x=df['date'], y=df['confirmed'])
plt.show()
```

The graph:
[image]

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: day level in x-axis is very difficult. so better try month level or `plt.xticks(rotation=70)` will rotate the x-axis labels

Comment: you may be right, I also thought labeling every month would be a better idea, do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the interval of `mdates.DayLocator(interval=14)` in order to control the time series data of x-axis. In this case, it is set to two weeks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

sns.barplot(x=df['date'], y=df['confirmed'], ax=ax)

ax.set_title("Daily Tests")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of confirmed cases")
ax.set_xlabel("Date")

days = mdates.DayLocator(interval=14)
days_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(days_fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]